# Display resolution reverted to default after software update Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce, dvi

I was Running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a Single monitor Benq 24" with an NVIDIA GK106 GEforce GTX660 card. Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-455

I accepted software updates and after the updates and a system reboot my monitor display changed from 1920x1080 screen resolution to 1280x1024 default screen resolution.

I couldn't find any way in Settings Manager => Display or ARandR to see the screen resolution I had been using. It was only showing the default resolution.

If I go into Settings Editor ==> Displays it shows the Default at 1280x1024 but also lists at DVI-I-O with BENQ 24 with the higher resolution of 1920x1080.

I did an OS upgrade to 20.04 LTS in the hope this might fix the issue. Alas no luck. I ran lshw and xrandr to give these readings:

```
   lshw -c video
```

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK106 [GeForce GTX 660]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e8000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
   xrandr
```

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
```

I also ran cvt if there was a way to add the resolution via command line:

```
  cvt 1920 1080
```

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz 
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

How do I get the display to access DVI-I-O with BENQ 24 with the higher resolution of 1920x1080? I can't seem to add this option in the System Settings Display dialog, and it certainly is not self-detecting.

Step by step GUI or command line instructions appreciated please to fix this issue.